# Ads services in android app

Tags: android, ads

I would like to seen some advice from the seniors here.

As stated by some write ups there are ads services which will collect the user data without the user knowledge. Is this true?

I looked into a couple of ads services but nothing is state about the info whether they will collect the user data without their knowledge.

What ads services do you recommend which is safe for the user of the app without their information been collect?

My primary purpose is to protect the user's data.

Comment: ad services are disgusting. They break your layout, destroy UI and collect user's data. All apps I've seen with ads looks terrible. Make it free and clean or sell it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check their privacy policies, every Ad services do have their privacy policy, and they tell information they collect from users and for what purpose they do.

[ChartBoost's privacy policy.](https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/200780269-Privacy-Policy)

Answer (score -1):

There is no way for you to know if an ad service is collecting user's data. I doubt they'll admit it even if they do. You can use AdMob which is owned by Google, which means that they have no need to collect extra data.

I had some experience in the past with different ad services, but I never though about this issue, so AdMob is the only one I can safely point out.